# cubic bezier to quadratic

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, opengl, bezier, spline

I have to write a function that converts cubic bezier (start, end, cp1, cp2) to simple quadratic (start, end, cp1) instances (one cubic can turn to 2 or more quadratic).

Any coding language is accepted, I just need the algorithm.

Comment: This article may gove some good hints: http://www.timotheegroleau.com/Flash/articles/cubic_bezier_in_flash.htm

Comment: clarification: 1) is there a way? 2) best approximation

Comment: great link, i wonder why i couldn't find it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I've decided to implement it by my own, with a lineto loop, similar to this:
http://www.paultondeur.com/2008/03/09/drawing-a-cubic-bezier-curve-using-actionscript-3/

Answer (score 4):

There are certain shapes, like circles, which can be approximated good enough by cubic *but not* by quadratic bezier. So from a purely mathematical point of view, the task can not be solved.

It is however possible, of course, to approximate a single cubic bezier with a set of piecewise quadratic beziers. The enpoints of each quadratic would lie on the exact points of the cubic. The control points you'd find by some means of optimization (least squares, or something similar) where you try to minimize the difference between the cubic and the quadratic bezier.

Comment: While true that there are shapes that can be represented by a cubic and not a quadratic Bezier curve, a circle cannot be represented by either. It can be approximated though.

Comment: @MikePedersen: Thanks. I reworded my answer.

Comment: @datenwolf "There are certain shapes, like circles, which can be approximated good enough by cubic but not by quadratic bezier. So from a purely mathematical point of view, the task can not be solved." Hmm... This is still misleading.